# Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have SharedValue Class where i have value, key and autosave using Shared_Value Package
Following are the code of shared_value

```
import 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart';

final SharedValue<bool> is_logged_in = SharedValue(
  value: false, // initial value
  key: "is_logged_in", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<String> access_token = SharedValue(
  value: "", // initial value
  key: "access_token", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<int> user_id = SharedValue(
  value: 0, // initial value
  key: "user_id", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<String> avatar_original = SharedValue(
  value: "", // initial value
  key: "avatar_original", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<String> user_name = SharedValue(
  value: "", // initial value
  key: "user_name", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<String> user_email = SharedValue(
  value: "", // initial value
  key: "user_email", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

final SharedValue<String> user_phone = SharedValue(
  value: "", // initial value
  key: "user_phone", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);
```

I am trying to get value of SharedValue in my main.dart class
but it not getting the value

```
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  fetch_user() async {
    var userByTokenResponse = await AuthRepository().getUserByTokenResponse();

    if (userByTokenResponse.result == true) {
      is_logged_in.value = true;
      user_id.value = userByTokenResponse.id;
      user_name.value = userByTokenResponse.name;
      user_email.value = userByTokenResponse.email;
      user_phone.value = userByTokenResponse.phone;
      avatar_original.value = userByTokenResponse.avatar_original;
    }
  }
```

it not accessing to the value of Shared class and give the following error

```
The setter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'SharedValue<bool>'.  
Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
```

kindly answer How to solve this.

Comment: paste your SharedValue class here

Comment: I already did it check the code above                                                               
import 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart';

final SharedValue<bool> is_logged_in = SharedValue(
  value: false, // initial value
  key: "is_logged_in", // disk storage key for shared_preferences
  autosave: true, // autosave to shared prefs when value changes
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
user_id.value = userByTokenResponse.id;
```

With:

```
user_id.$ = userByTokenResponse.id;
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem but with Paint'The setter 'enableDithering' isn't defined for the type 'Paint'.
Try importing the library that defines 'enableDithering', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'enableDithering'

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ninebot_app/pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Sadly your answer (and comment) are fairly incomprehensible.  Please look at some existing, upvoted answers for how they are formatted. You can click on the *"Edit"* button under any post to see the Markdown used to create it. Also read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting) and the 
[Markdown help](/editing-help).  Then [Edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78172419/edit) to try to improve it.  Thank you!